# Independent vs Dependent Scenarios in feature files (Cucumber Java-Maven)?

Tags: cucumber-java

We have 30 000 Scenarios and trying to use cucumber with maven(No test NG), and really big project. Dependent scenarios will stop us to pick only one part of Test Suit or one Test Case from Manual Test Plan on the other hand Independent scenarios will significantly increase time for test execution (if you start regression than it is almost waist of time).

Is answerer something between?
e.g.
Use independent where can, and divide dependent into functionalities and put them into separate feature files which are based on functionalities?

What is the best practice for writing feature files for big projects?
Dependent VS Independent
Functional Feature Files vs US feature files.

Answer (score 0):

That is question for you and your team, you have to get together and decide what is the best solution for you guys.

Someone here can give you his point of view, but you guys know what is best for your project needs.

In general, it is not a good idea to have dependent tests, as they are harder to maintain and if dependency breaks then all of your tests will fail and produce false negatives. Also if your important factor is time when doing automated regression testing then perhaps find middle ground, and your solution will be there.